# Second-order nonhomogenous differential equation $y''-6y'+5y=3e^t$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation
$$y''-6y'+5y=3e^t$$
I have problem with finding particular solutions.

Find $r_+,r_-$ roots of the characteristic polynomial of the equation above.
$$r_+=5,r_-=1$$
Find $y_+,y_-$, real-valued fundamental solutions to the differential equation. These solutions must satisfy the initial conditions
$$y_+=e^{5t},y_-=e^t$$
$$y_+(0)=1,\ y'_+(0)=5$$
$$y_-(0)=1,\ y'_-(0)=1$$

---

Now I need to find a particular solution $y_p$ to the nonhomogeneous equation. If I try to guess according to my table:
$$y_p=y'=y''=ke^t$$
Plugging it into the original equation:
$$ke^t-6ke^t+5ke^t=3e^t$$
but the left hand side is zero so I can't find a particular solution this way. Any other way?

Comment: Try $y_p=k\cdot te^t$ instead. This is the standard Ansatz when your inhomogeneous part is actually a zero of the homogeneous ODE (it's like having a double root in the char polynomial, so to say)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the ansatz $y=Ate^t$ where $A$ is a constant to be determined. This has derivatives
$$y'=A(t+1)e^t$$
$$y''=A(t+2)e^t$$
The differential equation requires
$$y''-6y'+5y=3e^t$$
$$A((t+2)e^t-6(t+1)e^t+5te^t)=3e^t$$
$$A((t+2)-6(t+1)+5t)=3$$
The $t$'s in the LHS cancel out, since 1 is a root of $x^2-6x+5=0$:
$$-4A=3\qquad A=-\frac34$$
Therefore a solution to the inhomogeneous equation is $y=-\frac34te^t$ and the general solution is
$$y=Ae^t+Be^{5t}-\frac34te^t$$
where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really bad at guessing (like me), you could use what's called *Variation of parameter*. It works like this. First, we compute the Wronskian of two solutions to the corresponding homogeneous equation.

$$W(y_1,y_2)=
        \begin{vmatrix}
        e^{5t} & e^t \\
        5e^{5t} & e^t\\
        \end{vmatrix}
        =e^{6t}-5e^{6t}=-4e^{6t}
$$

Then you can find a particular solution using

$$y_p=-y_1\int\frac{y_2(t) g(t)}{W(y_1,y_2)}dt+y_2\int\frac{y_1(t) g(t)}{W(y_1,y_2)}dt$$

In our case, $g(t)=3e^t$. Plug in, we have

$$y_p=-e^{5t}\int\frac{3e^{2t}}{-4e^{6t}}dt+e^t\int\frac{3e^{6t}}{-4e^{6t}}dt=-\frac{3}{16}e^{t}-\frac{3}{4}te^t$$

As you can see, you already have the $e^t$ part, so you only need the $te^t$ part.

You can read more about this method here: http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/second/variation/variation.html